# JavaMail Connection using Main Method and Some other Thread

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I am trying to connect to a gmail inbox to listen to messages using the JavaMail api. I can connect fine to the mailbox when I run my program through the main method. However when I create a separate thread and run it using some other class it seems that I get the following exception.

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: null; nested exception is:
    java.io.IOException
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:298)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:234)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:135)
    at com.emdi.sl3.server.emailConnector.EmailListenerAcknowledge.run(Email ListenerAcknowledge.java:92)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

My code to connect to the mailbox looks like,

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.event.*;

import com.sun.mail.imap.*;

public class EmailListenerAcknowledge implements Runnable {

    private Store store;
    private Folder folder;
    String host;
    String user;
    String password;

    public void run() {

        try {
            // TODO: Set email protocol, username and password.
            host = "imap.gmail.com";
            user = "fdsfds";
            password = "sdfsff";

            String mbox = "inbox";

            String frequency = "1";

            System.out.println("\nTesting monitor\n");

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.ssl.enable", "true");
            props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993"); 

            // Get a Session object
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props);

            // Get a Store object
            store = session.getStore("imap");

            // Connect
            store.connect(host, user, password);
            System.out.println("Connected!!!");

            // Open a Folder
            folder = store.getFolder(mbox);
            if (folder == null || !folder.exists()) {
                System.out.println("Invalid folder");
                System.exit(1);
            }

            folder.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I also notice that when I remove the line `props.setProperty("mail.imap.port", "993")`, I get a different exception (again running the program from the main method works fine),

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connection timed out: connect; nested exception is:java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:298)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:234)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:135)
    at com.emdi.sl3.server.emailConnector.EmailListener.run(Email ListenerAcknowledge.java:92)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`
```

I seem not to understand why running the program from the main method works fine whereas running the program from a separate thread don't work.

Comment: I would make the `EmailListenerAcknowledge` variables local to run to be thread safe.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You mean putting those variables inside the run() method for example. Tried that, but didn't have any effect.

Comment: Yeah, don't know what is going wrong, but is some other thread changing the values?

Comment: I thought about this too, but no other thread seems to change the values.

Comment: I don't see an obvious error in your code.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  (Note that you shouldn't need to set the port number, JavaMail will use the appropriate default port.)

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for the reply. For unsuccessful runs it just prints out the line, DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Sun Microsystems, Inc] whereas for successful runs it prints,

Comment: DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
...... along with other details.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but seems that Ant is reading the wrong javamail.default.providers file in the META-INF folder. For this project, I imported the mail.jar and placed it with higher priority than j2ee.jar since j2ee.jar already has an implementation of the JavaMail api (but it seems to lack certain functions such as idle()). Any ideas on how to point to the correct jar file to get the META-INF folder?

Comment: You never, ever, ever, need j2ee.jar (or javaee.jar) in your classpath when you're running your program.  If you're running in a Java EE application server, it provides it for you.  If you're not running in a Java EE application server, you need the full implementations of the APIs you're using, not just the API definitions in the j2ee/javaee jar file.

Comment: JavaMail depends on the thread's context class loader to find the configuration file.  If your different threads have different context class loaders, that would explain why you're getting different results.

Comment: @Bill Shannon: Now I understand it more clearly. So it means that the different threads load different classes due to their context class loaders being different. Is setting up a new context class loader for the thread that using JavaMail the correct way to go. I haven't used class-loaders before and I am trying to wrap my mind around how to resolve this problem. :)

Comment: Normally a thread will inherit the context class loader from its parent.  If you're doing something more interesting with threads or class loaders, you're going to need to set the thread's context class loader appropriately.  Application servers should take care of this for you.

Comment: I see. I checked the classloaders for both threads and it seems that when I run using the main method the class loaders are;Class = class sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader and 
Parent = sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader@22c510 whereas using the other thread its; Class = class com.evermind._ih
Parent = sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@6bc7c054

Comment: I am trying out with setting the classloaders but still didn't have success. On another approach, I tried to alter the package path of mail.jar using the jar jar utility (https://code.google.com/archive/p/jarjar/) but still it doesn't seem to solve the problem. I tried to eliminate j2ee.jar from the project, but it seems that our project is too dependent on it and whatever I do it seems to give eclipse errors. Is there any method that I can alter the name of the Javamail packages in the jar so that there's no conflict? I mean like using the jar jar utility.

Comment: @Bill: Thanks for your help. Managed to solve this issue, it was a Orion application server issue. :)